# Custom circular ProgressBar with image in center

Tags: android, progressdialog

For my android application I want put an image in a `circular progress bar`.
Expected design:

> http://hpics.li/cd6acba

Any ideas on how to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can take a normal layout file:
loader.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:clickable="false">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small.Inverse"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:padding="30dp"
        android:clickable="false"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/img"
        android:clickable="false"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Do the little adjustment according to your design.

Now use this layout as your progress dialog drawable.

Comment: The opening tag is a RelativeLayout but the closing tag is a LinearLayout. I don't think that would compile.

Comment: Nice catch. Have modified the code. @Sriram

Answer (score 7):

1. Create the animation xml :

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <animated-rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:drawable="@drawable/progress_bar"
       android:pivotX="50%"
       android:pivotY="50%" />
   ```
2. Set the following to your progressbar view in layout xml:

   ```
   android:indeterminateDrawable="@animator/progressbar_animation"
   ```