# How to use gif image in progress bar

Tags: android, progress-bar

I have tried all code but i can't find solution how use this (GIF)image in my progessbar

**XML file**

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    style="@style/GenericProgressIndicator"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="200px"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/animation" >
</ProgressBar>
```

**JAVA File**

```
ProgressBar  bar=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
```

**Want to use this image in progress bar**
[image: Want to use this image in progress bar]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use ProgressBar to show a GIF, unless you want to use special functionality that ProgressBar provides (does not look like it).

It's enough to use simple ImageView and some image library that supports GIFs (eg [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)).

Answer (score 1):

this is a trick instead of a full solution
i load the gif as an image in alert dialog box with transparent background
and show this alert dialog at start of process and dismiss it at the end.

However have a look at this too:
[Custom circular ProgressBar with image in center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29229490/custom-circular-progressbar-with-image-in-center)

Comment: Thanx for your interest can i set GIF image in alert dialog box?

Comment: yes but you need to create a custom dialog which contains an imageview and the root layout has transparent background.You can then set the source of this imageview to your local gif

Answer (score -1):

1. First Convert your Gif image to png Slice image sequence.
2. Declare Your Progress bar as Image view.

```
<ImageView
             android:id="@+id/ivProgress"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_gravity="center"
             android:visibility="visible" />
```

3. Create a **.xml** file in a drawable folder using your .png sequence image those are generated from gif.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <animation-list    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:oneshot="false">
        <item
            android:drawable="@mipmap/wblod_0"
            android:duration="40" />
        <item
            android:drawable="@mipmap/wblod_1"
            android:duration="40" />
        <item
            android:drawable="@mipmap/wblod_2"
            android:duration="40" />
        <item
            android:drawable="@mipmap/wblod_3"
            android:duration="40" />
        <item
            android:drawable="@mipmap/wblod_4"
            android:duration="40" />
        <item
            android:drawable="@mipmap/wblod_5"
            android:duration="40" />
        <item
            android:drawable="@mipmap/wblod_6"
            android:duration="40" />
        <item
            android:drawable="@mipmap/wblod_7"
            android:duration="40" />
        <item
            android:drawable="@mipmap/wblod_8"
            android:duration="40" />
        <item
            android:drawable="@mipmap/wblod_9"
            android:duration="40" />
        <item
            android:drawable="@mipmap/wblod_10"
            android:duration="40" />
        <item
            android:drawable="@mipmap/wblod_11"
            android:duration="40" />
        </animation-list>
```

4. In your activity set code like this.

```
private AnimationDrawable animationDrawable;
private ImageView mProgressBar;
mProgressBar.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.loading_web_animation);
animationDrawable =(AnimationDrawable)mProgressBar.getBackground();
mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
animationDrawable.start();
mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
animationDrawable.stop();
```

Comment: It would be great if you mentioned the reason for the downvote